# Removing all line-breaks (BRs)

Tags: jquery, line-breaks

I'd like to remove all `<br/>` `<br />` or `<br>` tags from `#id p`. I tried `$('#id p').find('br').remove();` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do it would be...

```
$('#id p br').remove();
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads-up, mine worked. I was accessing the element by ID, whereas it was a CLASS, uh! :)

Answer (score 6):

I tried out this example, and it worked for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test!</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foobar">
        <p>
            This is <br/> some <br/> text.
        </p>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="$('#foobar p').find('br').remove();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything different from what you are trying to do?

Comment: Could also do `$('#foobar p br').remove();` . Also, check out http://jsbin.com/ . It's awesome. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to search for `BR` tage within a paragraph with a particular ID? If so, I think that would be that would be `p#id` instead (I'm no JQuery expert, but it tends to follow CSS selectors).